# VS Code Ubuntu 16.04. После подключения ftp файлы открывает пустые

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

После обновления установленных приложений. Возникла непонятная ошибка. При подключении к серверу sftp файлы VS Code адекватно открывают однако при открытии файлов после подключения ftp файлы открывает пустые подскажите куда копать?

Comment: А как именно ты подключаешься?

Comment: пробовал подключения через расширение SFTP так же на прямую через менеджеры FileZilla и PCmanFM при чем данная ошибка на всех новых версиях VSCode. На версии  1.33.1 работают все 3 вида подключения корректно

Comment: Стоп. `sftp` или `ftp`? Или оба сразу?

Comment: не работает на FTP при SFTP подключении все нормально

Comment: Эммм... `curlftpfs`?

Comment: не совсем понимаю что вы имеете ввиду под: "curlftpfs"

Comment: Примонтировать ftp как локальный каталог.

Comment: Дон, если не сложно давайте свяжемся в скайп/телега/вайбер

Comment: У меня только jabber.

Comment: почтовый ящик? более развернуто опишу с приложением скринов и тд

Comment: Ну для картинок можно имгур.